# How do I dump a Sybase database in quiesced mode

Tags: sybase

I am trying to do a cross-platform (Sun -> Windows) dump and load of a Sybase ASE 15 database. The first time I tried, I got an error saying that the database needed to be in quiesced mode during the backup. What does this mean, and how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quiescing a database suspends updates to the database. Essentially making sure nothing happens to the data data while you're dumping or doing some other action.

Note: "hold_tag" can be any string you choose.

From isql (or whatever you use to connect to the db), just run (as sa, or equivalent)

```
quiesce database hold_tag hold database, database, etc
```

To resume operation run

```
quiesce database hold_tag release
```

In your case I would specify that you intend to do a dump

```
quiesce database hold_tag hold database for external dump
```

Also take a look at the docs here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands73.htm

Comment: My pleasure, I hope it worked for you.